# The association \Entity\Specialists#images refers to the owning side field Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media#spec which does not exist

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine, sonata

```
class Media extends BaseMedia

    /**
 * @var Specialists
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Specialists", inversedBy="images")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="spec", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $spec;

class Specialists

/**
 * @var Media
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", mappedBy="spec")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="images", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $images;
```

После php app / console doctrine: schema: validate
выдает ошибку

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Specialists\SpecialistsBundle\Entity\Specialists' mapping is invalid:
>   * The association Specialists\SpecialistsBundle\Entity\Specialists#images refers to the owning side field Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media#spec which does not exist.

брал ответ с [Symfony Sonata Media Bundle add images/videos to a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921077/symfony-sonata-media-bundle-add-images-videos-to-a-user?rq=1#29066210)

буду благодарен за ответ

Answer (score 1):

У вас неймспейс в OtM аннотации `Media::$spec` пропущен. Может, в этом проблема?